# Altium Components Panel missing "ALL" in dropdown

Tags: altium

I'm new to Altium and the version I'm using is 22.7.1. In most tutorials I see that in the components panel, there is "ALL" option in the dropdown menu as in the following image:

[image]

But in my case I do not have it:

[image]

As consequence when I search in my libraries I don't get results from all of them and I have to search within them one by one...

Is this due to a version difference?

Any solutions to overcome this issue?

Answer (score 1):

I am providing this information as a potential answer because it is too lengthy for a comment.

[The documentation](https://www.altium.com/documentation/altium-designer/schematic-searching-placing-components#!components-panel-access) mentions that this pull-down menu is a category selection:

> The panel's Categories pane (or the drop-down menu in compact mode) lists all available Workspace components under the All category entry and any available libraries.

From this I would infer that having a workspace set up is a prerequisite for the "All" category to be available.

Some settings to investigate for this:

- Preferences > System > Network Activity; check Data Management Server
- Preferences > Data Management > Servers

Like you, I do not have an "All" option in this menu. I do not use workspaces, so I am unsure if this is the correct solution.

Comment: Thanks for sharing. Since we are in the same situation, do you also have to repeat your search for each category? Or there is some trick to search once and get the results from all your local databases?

Comment: PS: I find "File-based libraries Search..." in the hamburger menu too complicated and not user friendly for repeated use!

Comment: @AKTanara At my company we use just one file-based library so the ability to search multiple libraries is not needed. If you happen to discover the solution please come back and post it as I'm curious!